# Adding a number as a suffix to multiple columns

Tags: awk

I have data that looks like:

```
chr1    enhancer_   875557  876449  .   enhancer_
chr1    enhancer_   876970  877622  .   enhancer_
chr1    enhancer_   995719  996320  .   enhancer_
chr1    enhancer_   1142786 1143060 .   enhancer_
```

I would like to add increasing numbers to the ends of columns 2 and 6 using awk. So the output would look like:

```
chr1    enhancer_1  875557  876449  .   enhancer_1
chr1    enhancer_2  876970  877622  .   enhancer_2
chr1    enhancer_3  995719  996320  .   enhancer_3
chr1    enhancer_4  1142786 1143060 .   enhancer_4
```

I've spent a good majority of the time looking, but haven't been able to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### solution 1:

```
awk '{print $1 " " $2 NR " " $3 " " $4 " " $5 " " $6 NR}' yourfile.txt
```

[image: solution 1 screenshot]

#### solution 2:

```
awk '{$2 = $2 NR; $6=$6 NR; print }' yourfile.txt
```

[image: solution2 screenshot]

#### sequencer for each replace

in case if you prefer sequencing each replacement, a perl version

```
perl -pe 's/enhancer_/$& .++$n/ge' yourfile.txt
```

[image: perl solution with sequence]

Comment: In the future, if would be much more helpful to have a pasted output of the text instead of a screenshot.  You can quickly turn pasted output into monospace font by selecting and clicking the "Code Sample" `{}` button.

Comment: I have some restrictions to copy from my corporate network (virtual desktop)to public network

Comment: @user1717828, thanks for your comment. In future, I will try to put textual data in code section.

Answer (score 2):

This only insert numbers and keep extra lines spaces of your example.

```
awk '{gsub(/enhancer_/,"enhancer_"NR); print;}'  fileinput.txt
```

output:

```
chr1    enhancer_1   875557  876449  .   enhancer_1
chr1    enhancer_2   876970  877622  .   enhancer_2
chr1    enhancer_3   995719  996320  .   enhancer_3
chr1    enhancer_4   1142786 1143060 .   enhancer_4
```